# Re-Subscribing the user for the Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, subscriber, sms, sendsmsactivity

Right now the user has opted out by sending the "STOP" keyword to the Long code. 
If that user wants to re-subscribe again then what are the possible ways to re-subscribe in Mobile Connect?

I found the way like manually changing the status to going to the contact which I don't want to do.

Another thing which I got is "Mobile Opt-in" template in the Mobile Connect but I'm not getting that who it works? I also tried to configure that but can not figure out this **"Subscription Options"**

- Single Opt-in - Requires users to text once to opt in. Double Opt-in
- Requires users to text twice to confirm opt-in.
- Double Opt-in with Age Confirmation - Requires users to text in their age after texting to opt in. If the user's age is above the minimum, MobileConnect accepts the opt-in.

And what is this "Subscriber will receive __ message(s) every Month/Weekly" is this the limit of sending SMS which we set need to set? 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using API to re-activate contacts for SMS channel?

Comment: No I've not tried that but creating "Mobile Opt-in" SMS worked me to opt-in contacts again but still I've not got  what is this "Subscriber will receive __ message(s) every Month/Weekly" is this the limit of sending SMS which we set need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile subscriber would need to use your “JOIN” keyword to opt back in or if you had a custom preference page using an API to MobileConnect.

The frequency of messages per month should match what is in your Terms & Conditions.

Comment: Thank you @jackson for the response, No I'm not using the custom preference center. I've configured the "Mobile Opt-in" SMS to resubscribe customer by using 'START' keyword. what I don't understand is that SMS count, **So that number of SMS is just a frequency capping per month right?**

Comment: Yes I believe so